# Is it possible to get the age of a session?

Tags: coldfusion

Client wants me to create a modal that comes up when the user has been on the site for 1 minute. I think this is bad for usability but they are pretty set on the idea.

Once the user clicks the close button, I'll set a session variable so that the modal doesn't appear again.

But I'm not sure about how to get how long the user has been on the site. Or should I be looking at cookies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach. Similarly to what @Antony suggested, create a varibale with the session start time...

Then on each page (say in application.cfm) you have CF code like this:

```
<cfset msRemaining = getTickCount() - session.sessionStart>
<cfif msRemaining lt 60*1000 and !session.modalShown>
    <script>
       setTimeout(showModel(), <cfoutput>#msRemaining#</cfoutput>);
    </script>
</cfif>
```

The idea is to calculate how many milliseconds remain until you need to show the modal. If less than 60 seconds, you add a javascript block which will call your `showModal()` javascript function after that many milliseconds. Otherwise, you simply do not generate the block...

Comment: Thank you. This was a really good answer. In case anyone is using this answer on their project, please note that it should be <cfset msRemaining = (60*1000) - (getTickCount() - session.sessionStart)>

Answer (score 1):

An approach to consider has two parts:

Firstly, when the session starts, add the current time (or [tickcount](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/GetTickCount)) to the session and set a modalshown flag to false:

`sample code:
 <cfset session.sessionStart = getTickCount() />
 <cfset session.modalshown = false />`

Secondly, your front end can use ajax polling to request the current user's sessionStart time and show a modal when the sessionStart time is more than 60 seconds ago.  You would also need to set a flag on the session once the modal has been shown so you don't show the modal every time after 60 seconds.

`sample code:
<cfif getTickCount() - session.sessionStart gt 60*1000 and !session.modalShown>
  <cfset session.modalShown = true />
  <cfreturn true />
</cfif>`

By using ajax and the session scope it doesn't matter what coldfusion page they are browsing when the 60 seconds expire.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could think of would be to create a variable to represent 60 seconds when you create the session variable.

Then you could use that variable in a javascript function to count down and display the modal at 0.

Comment: But wouldn't this only work if they stay on the same page for 60 seconds?